# iOS: Request header field SOAPAction is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: typescript, soap, xmlhttprequest

I am using ionic v3 I am running the app in my iPhone using ionic Cordova run iOS. The app runs fantastic, but when it attempts to connect to the soap api to perform some operations the responseXML is null and I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.hostname.com/service.cfc?wsdl.**strong text** Request header field SOAPAction is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

This happens because I am sending: this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",""); [yes, with empty value, since it is like that in the request header].

And if that request header is not sent then the server returns 500 error.

I am in my device which shouldn't have any issue with cors. But I haven't found any documentation about this.

If you have any information about this, please leave a response.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @bvprogramit, can you add some code sample so others can better diagnose your problem at hand? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to me. 

I found an answer and it worked. Look at this:

http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/

Comment: Happy to help. And welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer and it worked. Look at this:

http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/